# Why when I use mutate command the index column tend to disappear?

Tags: r, dplyr

Using the data.frame mtcars, when I apply the mutate command, the index column from mtcars with cars names tend to disappear.

```
mtcars
mutate(mtcars, displ_l = disp / 61.0237)
```

I want to visualize the whole data.frame with new modifications. Could it be possible?

Thanks

Comment: It's not a column, they are row names, and `mutate` comes from a package written by someone who thinks row names are bad, so it returns an object with no row names. If you want to keep the row names, you'll need to move them to an actual column.

Comment: In the future, please add tags or put the names of packages in your question that you are using. `mutate` is not a base R function.

Comment: Thanks for your recommendations. I have already solved the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Then, the way to turn row names from data.frame into a column is by using this:
    setDT(df, keep.rownames = TRUE)[]

Comment: This relies on using the `data.table` package, which is tangential to the `dplyr` package that is asked about in the question. The `dplyr` way to do it would be `df = rownames_to_column(df)`.